# Number of squares formed by $m$ horizontal and $n$ vertical lines

Tags: combinatorics

(Considering the lines are equidistant.)

I tried finding them but I was only successful in finding the number of 1x1 squares
I tried using permutation and combination but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you find the number of $2\times2$ squares?

Comment: Is there a constraint that each side of the square must be either a horizontal line or a vertical line?  It is possible to construct a square that violates this constraint where all 4 corners of the square are *grid points*.

Comment: Imagine an $m \times n$ chessboard, where $m \leq n$.  Then the allowable square sizes are $\{(1\times 1), (2\times 2), \cdots, (m\times m)\}$.  Imagine enumerating all the possible ways of positioning the lower left hand corner of a $(k \times k)$ square, on the chessboard.  Clearly, the lower left hand corner of the chessboard is one allowable location.  What are the other allowable locations?  In fact, assuming the natural response to my previous comment/question, your original query reduces to consideration of possible locations for the lower left hand corner of the $(k \times k)$ square.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when you form a grid using $m$ horizontal and $n$ vertical lines, is it your intent that the size of the grid is $(m \times n)$ or $([m-1) \times [n-1])$?  That is, what size chessboard would the situation analogize to?

Comment: Do you see how to go from a $n \times n$ to a $(n+1) \times (n+1)$? If so, try to generalize this to non square grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m \leq n$, then you have

- $(m-1)\times(n-1)$ squares of size $\{1,1\}$
- $(m-2)\times(n-2)$ squares of size $\{2,2\}$
- ...
- $((m-1)-(m-1)+1)\times((n-1)-(m-1)+1)=(n-m+1)$ squares of size $\{m-1,m-1\}$

Then you need to sum them up:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{m-2} (m-i)\times(n-i) = \sum_{i=1}^{m-2} [mn -i(m+n) + i^2]
$$
I'll let you figure out the end :)

Comment: The number of $1\times1$ squares is $(m-1)\times(n-1)$.

Comment: ahhh yeah true, I edited my answer

Comment: Now the number of the largest squares is wrong.

Comment: Its the number of squares other than 1x1...if we want to get the total number of squares then the limit should be $(m-1)$ instead of $(m-2)$

Comment: Can you please add that limit thing(i don't have the edit privilege)